# How to set locale in Windows 10 in general and for or gawk

Tags: windows, batch-file, awk, locale

gawk seems to count bytes and not characters for Unicode strings.

I am trying to set LOCALE to get around this problem and also format dates, numbers with decimals and numbers over a 1000 in local representation conventions.

I tried to set in a batch (.bat) file locale as follows without any effect on gawk results.

```
    set LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
    c:\tools\awk\gawk -f try.awk
```

and     also as

```
    set LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
    c:\tools\awk\gawk -f try.awk
```

Does someone know how to do this?

I am using GNU Awk 3.1.6 and have Windows 10 build 19042.1348

Comment: That's an extremely old version of gawk, it's 15 years out of date as we're now on version 5.1.1 which has a ton of bug fixes and additional functionality. You might want to update your gawk version.

Comment: Think you. Where van I downloaded it from?

Question remains hoe to set locale in batch file.

Also, does version 5.1.1 solve the Unicode and locale issues  noted in my post?

Comment: Your question is not about a specific issue with your provided code, it is requesting information on how to configure Operating System/software, and as such is more suited to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Comment: The gawk I use is by GNU and the version number I noted is unrelated to Unix, Linux, etc. gawk.

Comment: @David GNU awk IS gawk and AFAIK the version number is the same whether it's built for Unix or Windows. It'd be extremely confusing if that wasn't the case. I see some instructions at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#PC-Installation that might be useful and you could always email the gawk providers if not.